# IIS giving 503s with "A system shutdown is in progress. (0x8007045b)" after enabling Suspend on Application Pool

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016, asp.net

I have several ASP.NET Core websites on a Windows Server 2016 VM running in IIS/Kestrel (reverse proxy configuration).

Some of these websites have some inactivity time during the day. Because of that, their Application Pool is terminated (and I would like to keep that to use fewer resources). The problem is that cold-start was taking a quite long time. I then setup these app pools to `Suspend` instead of `Terminate` after idling out.

Since then, these websites are not only taking *longer* to start when cold, but also have been giving out 503s in some of the cold starts. Once they're started, they work normally. But the first hit on a suspended app pool is almost always a 503. The body contains a message like "The service is unavailable", but translated (and not in UTF-8, it seems, since characters are not correctly rendered). I'm not sure if this message is coming from IIS or Kestrel.

After looking for Failed Request Traces, I found this:

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-10-24T15:13:51.803Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000C51-0003-BC00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13656" ThreadID="17072"/>
  <Computer>[REDACTED]</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000C51-0003-BC00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">AspNetCoreModuleV2</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">128</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">503</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Server has been shutdown</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">2147943515</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">A system shutdown is in progress.
 (0x8007045b)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: Just for Google to find your posting; I'm having the same issue, just with a different `HttpReason` value of "**Application Shutting Down**". No solution, so far.

Comment: In my case, the solution was to multiple times restart IIS. Strange thing, never had this ever before. Another ASP.NET Core MVC 6 project on the same server (Azure VM with Windows Server 2022) worked without any issues. 